# Calling stored procedure from c# returns "?????" in varchar response

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, ado.net, sql-server-2016

When I call a stored procedure on a SQL-Server from C#, using ADO.NET, I receive following response in my output-parameter:
[image]

Literally `??????` as a `VarChar`.

My stored procedure looks like this:

```sql
ALTER Procedure [sp_getEncryptedPassword]
 (@PublicKey nvarchar(128), @UserId uniqueidentifier,  @PasswordClearText varchar(255) OUTPUT, @resOUT int OUTPUT, @rowsOUT int OUTPUT)

AS
    SET NOCOUNT On

    DECLARE @LinkIsValid bit = 0;
    set @rowsOUT=0

    while (@LinkIsValid=0)
    begin

        SELECT  CONVERT(nvarchar, DecryptByPassphrase(@PublicKey, UserpasswordEncrypted, 1, CONVERT(varbinary, @UserId)))  AS PassWordClearText
        Into #TEMP1
        from UserLogin  
        WHERE Userid = @UserId

        set @rowsOUT=@@ROWCOUNT

        SET @LinkIsValid=1

    end

    if @rowsOUT=0
        SET @resOUT=1 

    select 'RStestPwd' as 'PasswordClearText', @resOUT as 'resOUT', @rowsOUT as 'rowsOUT'
```

I have removed some lines, but I hope you get the point.
As part of debugging, I have hardcoded a response - just to see if I get anything. And I do:
[image]

My C# code:

```cs
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(spName, con);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

SqlParameter pubKey = cmd.Parameters.Add("@PublicKey", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier);
pubKey.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
pubKey.Value = publicKey;

SqlParameter IdIn = cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserId", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier);
IdIn.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
IdIn.Value = userid;

SqlParameter pwdOUT = cmd.Parameters.Add("@PasswordClearText", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255);
pwdOUT.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

SqlParameter resOUT = cmd.Parameters.Add("@resOUT", SqlDbType.Int);
resOUT.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

SqlParameter rowsOUT = cmd.Parameters.Add("@rowsOUT", SqlDbType.Int);
rowsOUT.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

con.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();

result.Password = pwdOUT.Value.ToString();
```

Is it a part of the formatting between the SQL-server and my application?
Is it a setting in my SQL-server, my ADO.NET Command instance or my conntection string?

EDIT:
Thanks for your comments. I have reviewed my code, and modyfied places with (N)VarChar and so on.
Neither before or after these modifications, I get any exceptions - just the questionmarks. So the SP is working - but loose/modify data between database and application...

Comment: What's the code calling your stored procedure?

Comment: You have likely specified the parameter as `varchar` rather than `nvarchar` in C#.

Comment: `??` appears if you tried to read single-codepage text using the wrong codepage. Given this code it could also mean the entire process was wrong, resulting in bytes that can't be converted to characters. From a *security perspective*, it's *very bad*. Passwords should *never be encrypted*. They should be salted, hashed with a strong cryptographic algorithm for at least 1000 times. Only the hash can be stored

Comment: `SqlDbType.VarChar` is missing a `N`. Simple typo. Voting to close.

Comment: The fix is to change `varchar` to `nvarchar` **not the other way around** (in other words, you broke it more rather than applying the fix I suggested). Read my second comment. It was talking about C# code **not the stored proc**.

Comment: In summary, change **all** references to `varchar` to `nvarchar`. In both SQL **and** C#.

Comment: You are returning the password in the resultset. You are reading the output parameter from C#. You are not populating the output parameter from SQL.

Comment: Did you get it working?